# Open Build Service include gcc-6 compiler

Tags: opensuse, gcc6

I am using Open Build Service (https://build.opensuse.org/) and I need to include gcc-6 compiler since I am getting the following error in the build:

```
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++14 language features is required.
```

How can I add a repository for gcc-6 and then configure the yml file to use gcc-6 please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the target is some variant of SUSE Linux, add `BuildRequires: gcc-c++` to the rpm spec file. Depending on the target, the default gcc version might be too old to support C++14. In this case use a specific newer version, like `BuildRequires: gcc10-c++`. In the `%build` section, add `export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-10` before the `configure` call, to make it aware of the required compiler.

Other than that this question lacks almost all details to give a specific and helpful answer...

Comment: In addition: the system C++ compiler may support C++14 already. Use `-std=c++14` in `CXXFLAGS` to tell the compiler about the requirement to change the built-in default.